# how to print dynamic data in React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

so the problem is I´m trying to print data according to the length of an array. This is the solution I´ve tried. Of course it doesn´t work. I don´t completely know why but I´m sure it´s because the cb function in the forEach is not being processed as I want. Here´s the code:

```
function Users(props){
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([user]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users').then((res) =>{
            
            return res.json();
        }).then(res => {

            setUsers(res);
        });
    }, []);

    return (
            <div>
                {users.forEach((user) =>{
                    return(
                    <ul>
                        <li>{user.firstName}</li>
                        <li>{user.lastName}</li>
                        <li>{user.avatar}</li>
                    </ul>);})}
            </div>
        );
}
```

Comment: Use `map` instead of `forEach` to create an array of components you can render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
function Users(props){
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([user]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users').then((res) =>{
            
            return res.json();
        }).then(res => {

            setUsers(res);
        });
    }, []);

    return (
            <div>
                {users.map((user) =>{
                    return(
                    <ul>
                        <li>{user.firstName}</li>
                        <li>{user.lastName}</li>
                        <li>{user.avatar}</li>
                    </ul>);})}
            </div>
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as SwaD said or like this if you have nothing else to do except render your data :

```
function Users(props){
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([user]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users')
        .then( res => res.json() )
        .then(res => {
            setUsers(res);
        });
    }, []);

    return (
            <div>
                {users.map((user) => (
                    <ul>
                        <li>{user.firstName}</li>
                        <li>{user.lastName}</li>
                        <li>{user.avatar}</li>
                    </ul>)
                )}
            </div>
        );
}
```